# firebug: how to set watch when an <div id="abcd"> is changed by JS code?

Tags: ajax, firebug

I have a `<div id="abcd">` which is changed by other code, I want to find out who is chaning that, can I set up a watch expression so that I can catch it in FireBug?

Thanks.
Bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Firebug 1.5 or 1.6, use the Inspect to select the element, then in the HTML panel, right click on the element and select eg break on attribute change or another one as you need.

See http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html

Answer (score 1):

i don't know the exact wording in english, i use it in german. But if you click right on your div, there is a function called "explore element" (normally at the bottom of the context menu). Afterwords firebug displays that area where you can see all live changes...

Comment: after i read your question again, i notice that wasn't your problem, sorry for that. Nevertheless i am not sure, if this plan is possible, because you don't have access to that event which changes the element. If I were you, i would debug all the positions, where you changing the element. Then you can see, which function / event has done it ;-)